# Detecting KPI cell from Cellset when querying SQL 2005 Analysis Services

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, olap, mdx

Given an MDX query that may return KPI values, is there a way to query the cells in the cellset object to determine whether they are actually KPI's?  This way I can display trend/status images in the results instead of 0. -1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

What would signify that a value was a KPI? Only you know that!

But if the measure names included the letters "KPI" perhaps you could detect that (certain VB functions like InStr can be used within MDX if on Microsoft Analysis Services, but it would be simpler to just check the measure name as a whole).

The other way would be to set up member properties in the cube, and get the MDX to act differently based on that.